# How can i scroll to element by id using appium driver

Tags: javascript, java, scroll, appium

I want to scroll to an element in a page by id using `appium` driver.

I have tried the following:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
```

But its says not yet implemented.

Comment: I received the same error for drag and drop.
Try changing the context before running the executescript command.
driver.context("NATIVE_APP");

Comment: if you use java client make sure you use version 2.0+  and then use the already built in scroll to function, if this also did not work i would suggest to implement your own function using the swipe method as i did

Answer (score 0):

1.use scrollTo or scrollToExact method of appium 
2. Implement your swipe method using screen x y Co ordinates 
 After that Use while loop.. Check your element Id, if present click else swipe

Answer (score 0):

@karan use touch action class

```
new TouchAction((MobileDriver)driver).longPress(parentTextField.get(textField_index1)).moveTo(parentTextField.get(textField_index2)).release().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement page1 = driver.findElement(By.name(url));
((MobileElement) page1).swipe(SwipeElementDirection.UP, 7000);
```